# Trigonometric function Intuition

Tags: trigonometry

I am having trouble getting a conceptual grasp on trig functions. I know that are a way of relating angles and sides. But what bothers me is why we have to press a button on a calculator in order to use them. What is mathematically going on when I press the trig functions on my calculator? Why can't I just work them out on paper?

Comment: I really think you should read some information about trigonometry, for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions (up till section 2) There is a lot your are asking on your post and it seems to me that the basics are missing.

Comment: In the Olden Days, when I was in school, we had no calculators.  We had to use tables to look up the answers to trig problems.

Comment: @GEdgar. But using those (inverse) tables got us a much better understanding of what the meaning was of for example a sine...

Comment: I also had trig functions on my slide rule.

Comment: Allen, the answers come from the sin,cos and tan graphs.  if you punch sin 90 in your calculator you would get 1. You can also see  this on a sin graph when the x value is 90.  I hope this serves as a visual ad whenever you do trig problems..

Answer (score 1):

Your calculator is approximating these: http://math2.org/math/algebra/functions/sincos/expansions.htm

However you have learn the the concepts of trig and calculus before you can understand how these calculations work.

There is no obvious arithmetic relation between angles and the lengths of sides.  This is a new concept whose calculations are not built upon anything prior.  Obviously there is a geometric one so the only way to calculate these (except for special value ones such as 60 degrees or 45 degrees, etc) would be to draw really big pictures and measure them with a ruler.

You can calculate how to find trig values sums of angles and halfs of angles provided you know the trig values for the first angles, so you can find a way of approximating from simple angles, such as 30 degrees or 90 degrees, but these are only approximations.  There is no arithmetic that will tell you what the base of right triangle with an angle of such and such will have.

Let the experts before you who compiled the trig tables do it for you.

Comment: see also the CORDIC algorith. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC

Comment: True.  There are all sorts of ways to calculate these.  The question *seems* to be why we can't just use previous mathematical constructs to express trig functions.  The subtle point I'm trying to get across is that whereas arithmetic is built an a foundation (of counting more or less).  Trig is based on a different foundation (geometry).  But the two are related.  But you have to study both of them quite a bit to find the relation.  At the basic level trig as self-defined and "away" from arithmetic construct.  Arghh!  The language is so inadequate...

Answer (score 1):

Ptolemy published a table of chords, which is the precursor of the modern sine function. He worked out their values geometrically. It's labour-intensive.

[Here is my experience](http://adamhrankowski.weebly.com/blog/how-i-calculated-sin-54-with-my-bare-hands) calculating one sine manually.